# Server supplied Function in Javascript via JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I'm creating a data driven display using force graph from D3.

I supply the nodes and links from server data via ajax.

There is a function in D3 Force Layout model which allows you to set the link distance, via a function. I'd like to store this function(s) in a database or have them generated server side at the very least.

Here is a simple example.

```
        force
            .gravity(json_data.gravity || 0.15)
            .charge(-150 + json_data.nodes.length)
            .nodes(json_data.nodes)
            .links(json_data.links)
            .linkDistance(function (link, index) {
                if (index % 2)
                    return 30;
                return 50;
            })
            .start();
```

For fields like charge and linkDistance I'd really like the heavy lifting to be done server side.

Whats the "best" way of achieving this?  I understand there is something Eval might be able to solve but, most posts say avoid it..

Thoughts?

EDIT:

this is what I am trying to store

```
"function (link, index) { if (index % 2) return 30; return 50;"

"function (link, index) { if (index % 3 ==1) return 30; if (index % 3==2) return 40; return 50;"
```

Here's where I took it.

ServerSide :

```
    public JsonGraphDTO(int Id, UnitRepository repository) {
        gravity = 0.15;
        linkDistance = "return 40;";
        ...
```

Client Side Processing :

```
        var fn = new Function('lnk','index',json_data.linkDistance);
        force
            .gravity(json_data.gravity || 0.15)
            .charge(-150 + json_data.nodes.length)
            .nodes(json_data.nodes)
            .links(json_data.links)
            .linkDistance(fn)
            .start();
```

Comment: How would `eval` help with the serverside?

Comment: Is that supposed to be insightful? I don't know I learned javascript 2 weeks ago. I'm thinking that eval would allow you to compile the function body received from the server into an executable function?

Comment: So the JavaScript function is stored as JavaScript in a database, evaluated on the server and returned as a calculated value to the browser as part of a JSON?

Comment: No its evaluate client side. the function body is different for each graph. and the specifics of the function are to be stored in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be able to link to different functions, name them.

```
function linkDistance1 (link, index) { if (index % 2) return 30; return 50; }
function linkDistance2 (link, index) { if (index % 3 ==1) return 30; if (index % 3==2) return 40; return 50; }
```

and reference them

```
    force
        .gravity(json_data.gravity || 0.15)
        .charge(-150 + json_data.nodes.length)
        .nodes(json_data.nodes)
        .links(json_data.links)
        .linkDistance(linkDistance1)
        .start();
```

You can do it as an array

```
var linkDistanceFunctions = [
    function (link, index) { if (index % 2) return 30; return 50; },
    function (link, index) { if (index % 3 ==1) return 30; if (index % 3==2) return 40; return 50; }
];
```

or as an object

```
var linkDistanceFunctions = {
    "foo" : function (link, index) { if (index % 2) return 30; return 50; },
    "bar" : function (link, index) { if (index % 3 ==1) return 30; if (index % 3==2) return 40; return 50; }
};
```

You said you want to load them dynamically, so load them via a script tag.

```
window["myCallBack"] = function(myArrayOfFunctions){
    console.log(myArrayOfFunctions);
};
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'myServerSidePage.php?callback=myCallBack';
head.appendChild(script);
```

And on the server you would return the functions back with the call back

```
myCallBack([
    function (link, index) { if (index % 2) return 30; return 50; },
    function (link, index) { if (index % 3 ==1) return 30; if (index % 3==2) return 40; return 50; }
]);
```

I used an Array, you can send back an object or just a function if you want.

Comment: Can I move the generation of these function to the server and push them via JSON? There is a lot more data available on the server that I'd rather not send to the client. These functions are notional and for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: When it can not be JSON since JSON does not support functions. If you want to tust it go ahead. It might be better to do it as a script request.

Comment: I think this is the crux of the Eval dealie. Could I not use that to turn the json string into executable an function?

Comment: If you are returning code it will have to evaled one way or another. Only way you run into security problems is man in middle attacks [any page/file/call could be hit with that] or letting users set data and save it unclean in the database. If not, it is fine. My eidted answer above the same way how JSONP works, you have to trust the source you get the data from.

Comment: I understand this much, what I am attempting to avoid is the overwhelming sense that eval in this manner is akin to goto. I was looking for syntactic creativity that would allow for this without the use of eval.

Comment: There are times where you need to use `eval()` or `new Function()` and this is one of them. Eval is evil most of the time, with what you want to do it is not.

Comment: I would up vote you but I got down voted to hell because to hell after my response to your first remark. Thanks for the help.